# Why 'use-sound' is not getting imported?

Tags: reactjs, import

0

I have installed 'use-sound' package. But when I try to import it like this : import useSound from 'use-sound'

I get this error: Could not find a declaration file for module 'use-sound'. 'f:/netflix/spotify-clone/node_modules/use-sound/dist/use-sound.esm.js' implicitly has an 'any' type. There are types at 'f:/netflix/spotify-clone/node_modules/use-sound/dist/index.d.ts', but this result could not be resolved when respecting package.json "exports". The 'use-sound' library may need to update its package.json or typings.

I followed a youtube tutorial and it was working fine in that.

But I have installed it correctly, I checked package.json, the package is there.

I also tried using require: const usesound = require('use-sound') When I tried accessing it like this

const [play, { pause, sound }] = usesound.useSound(
songUrl,
{
volume: volume,
onplay: () => setIsPlaying(true),
onend: () => {
setIsPlaying(false);
onPlayNext();
},
onpause: () => setIsPlaying(false),
format: ['mp3']
}
); I get 'useSound is not a function', also tried like this const [play, { pause, sound }] = usesound.useSound(.... still getting the same error.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Looks like a known issue of use-sound in typescript projects: https://github.com/joshwcomeau/use-sound/issues/135